# Exponentiation on the power series expansion of exp(x)

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n$. I wish to show that for some positive integer $m$, $f(mx)=(f(x))^m$.

Now of course, one could always make the connection that $f(x)$ is just the power series expansion of $e^x$ and just use the rules of exponentiation to derive the desired result, but what if I don't know that $f(x)=e^x$?

What I did was take $(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n)^m$, apply the multinomial formula to it, and just kind of brute forced the algebraic manipulation to end up at the desired result. Is there some observation that I'm missing that can allow me to go from $f(mx)$ to $(f(x))^m$ without slogging through all the algebraic manipulation?

p/s: While writing this question, I think the use of the multinomial formula isn't quite the right choice either, since the result holds for more general $m$.

Comment: Have you tried using inducting over $m$? It suffices to prove it for positive $m$.

Comment: I'd start by proving that $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$ (and then your equality follows).